# Binding a date literal to a parameter in an Oracle SQL Developer query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query in Oracle that looks (in part) like this:

```
where Doc3.clinicalDate >= ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateBegin)
    and Doc3.clinicalDate < ml.convert_date_to_id(:DateEnd)
```

When I put this query in SSRS and set up the report and dataset parameters, it works fine. However, if I paste it into Oracle SQL Developer, it pops up a window asking me to "Enter Binds". When I put in "date '2011-06-01'", I get the error "ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected". How do I pass it the date in a format it will actually understand? Thanks.

Comment: That would depend on the default date format for your database.  Try 06-01-2011, 01-Jun-2011, 2011-06-01 (note: all without surrounding apostrophes which would make them strings).

Comment: 01-JUN-2011 was the ticket. :-) Would you be so kind as to put this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would depend on the default date format for your database. Try 06-01-2011, 01-Jun-2011, 2011-06-01 (note: all without surrounding apostrophes which would make them strings).

Answer (score 3):

That's a common problem. I change my query to use `to_date(:DateEnd,'DD/MM/YYYY')` - than it takes your date as varchar and converts to date.